# amavisd: Unrecognized character \xBB;

Tags: perl, amavis

I have a problem to start the amavisd. When I try to start with `/etc/init.d/amavis start`
I get the following error:

`Starting amavisd: Problem in Amavis::DKIM code: Unrecognized character \xBB; marked by <-- HERE after <-- HERE near column 1 at /usr/lib/perl5/Net/DNS/RR/Unknown.pm line 1.
Compilation failed in require at /usr/lib/perl5/Net/DNS/RR.pm line 15.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at /usr/lib/perl5/Net/DNS/RR.pm line 15.
Compilation failed in require at /usr/lib/perl5/Net/DNS/Packet.pm line 16.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at /usr/lib/perl5/Net/DNS/Packet.pm line 16.
Compilation failed in require at /usr/lib/perl5/Net/DNS/Resolver/Base.pm line 25.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at /usr/lib/perl5/Net/DNS/Resolver/Base.pm line 25.
Compilation failed in require at /usr/lib/perl5/Net/DNS/Resolver/UNIX.pm line 9.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at /usr/lib/perl5/Net/DNS/Resolver/UNIX.pm line 9.
Compilation failed in require at /usr/lib/perl5/Net/DNS/Resolver.pm line 19.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at /usr/lib/perl5/Net/DNS/Resolver.pm line 22.
Compilation failed in require at /usr/lib/perl5/Net/DNS.pm line 91.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at /usr/lib/perl5/Net/DNS.pm line 91.
Compilation failed in require at /usr/share/perl5/Mail/DKIM/DNS.pm line 14.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at /usr/share/perl5/Mail/DKIM/DNS.pm line 14.
Compilation failed in require at /usr/share/perl5/Mail/DKIM/PublicKey.pm line 18.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at /usr/share/perl5/Mail/DKIM/PublicKey.pm line 18.
Compilation failed in require at /usr/share/perl5/Mail/DKIM/Signature.pm line 13.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at /usr/share/perl5/Mail/DKIM/Signature.pm line 13.
Compilation failed in require at /usr/share/perl5/Mail/DKIM/Verifier.pm line 13.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at /usr/share/perl5/Mail/DKIM/Verifier.pm line 13.
Compilation failed in require at (eval 95) line 47.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at (eval 95) line 47.
(failed).`

I think there is somthing like a BOM in any File. But where can I find it? I tryed to find the error with searching for the `\xBB` but no success.

Comment: I suggest starting with verifying the integrity of the installed packages. As for the configuration files, running `iconv -f ASCII -t ASCII` could help signaling which ones have problems.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem. There are many perl modules I forgot to install. I checked the dependencies and installed the modules. Now it runs very well